# web application with site per registered account

Tags: web-applications

I am planing to build a new web-based application.

The application is a (some kind of) management application for business**es**.

Each business owner will open a main account. This main account will have all needed functionality and they will be able to add users with permissions and roles.

While planning this application, I think this will get too big and messy.

So I thought of something "similar" to wordpress.com "way of registeration"

I want each main account registered to get an id and with that ID the system will create a new site withing my site for that account. I want this to be done automatically.

But I had another problem, Am I going to create a database for each user registering?

Any solution to this pattern of web applciation?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very general, and there are likely many ways to solve this. I've built sites that are similar, and the way I've generally solved it is:

- Each registered user gets a unique id, in your case maybe call it business_id
- All the other data in your database that is specific to that business, is also stored with the business_id. So if they create a user, with user_id, that needs to be mapped to business_id in a table somewhere
- This should avoid creating multiple databases (and I wouldn't do it that way - too complex). So long as your schema is put together with associations like the example above, you should be able to cleanly store everything within one DB.

If you want to review something very basic, a site I have using this method is http://www.mydancingclass.com. If you go to that URL, it will take you to the example site. But if you go to http://www.mydancingclass.com/?dcs, it will take you to a specific dance school (and there are many in there). You can see that the second site displays different text, logos, etc. The branding I have in place isn't very advanced (and even the URL handling can be done better), but hopefully that may give you some ideas.

Comment: Is there any cloud-related solution?

Comment: If you want to do something cloud-based, again, I'm thinking business_id is your key, whether it helps you identify business by location, load, etc. But you'd need analysis of your own data and site load to really break that down. None of my client sites are of the scale that require that kind of complexity - the above site could be scaled that way, but it would be overkill at the moment.